# Trouble enabling view modes for content types

Tags: 7, nodes, display-suite, entities

I have a custom view mode and need to enable it for a node type.  I need to enable it through my module, and it seemed like hook_entity_info_alter() is the way to go, but it's not working.  Am I missing something?

My code:

```
function mymod_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
    $entity_info['node']['view modes']['vm_mid_box'] = array(
        'custom settings' => TRUE,
        'label' => 'Mid Box'
    );
}
```

EDIT: I create the displays in Display Suite, and am using the export data dumped into DS hooks.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? And I have found in the past that when I do this I must first navigate after clearing the cache to the entity type's display page.

Comment: I do, obsessively.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but for anyone else looking, to get your view mode to display try either visiting the module page or disabling then re-enabling your module. Afterwards clear the cache.